# How to use the DragMoveBehaviorElement (drag) on a button in blend?

Tags: c#, wpf, blend, attachedbehaviors

i'm trying to make a draggable button in blend.
using the dragmovebehaviorelement on a button does nothing, and i think this is because a button already uses the LeftMouseButon_down event.

using this behavior on a shape (exp: ellipse) works fine.

is there a way to make a draggable button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use `MouseDragElementBehavior` with `Button` directly because the behavior will never receive the `LeftButtonDown` event.  However, if you are will to change your UI a little, it can be made to work.  For example, create a "thumb" that the user can drag to move the button and attach the behavior to the composite object.  Here's an example using a little red rectangle to the right of the button:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ei:MouseDragElementBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Button Content="Button">
    </Button>
    <Rectangle Fill="DarkRed" Width="20"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I see, well, that's exactly the same thing i did by myself,
only i used "Red" instead of "DarkRed" XD!

but it's good to have a confirmation i was right, thank you :)