# WPF DrawingImage Make Object Draggable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

We have existing program that uses DrawingVisual, DrawingContext and DrawingImage to draw object such as Rectangles, Angles, Lines, Squares etc. The customer is recently requesting if possible any drawn object is draggable so that it's easier for them to reposition the objects. The challenge in our program is that graphics are drawn in an Image within a canvas using DrawingImage. If we are going re-code the program and use Canvas the efforts will be big. It's like re-creating the whole module. I would like to ask help from you if it is possible to make drawn objects draggable either through left mouse hold and move or redraw the image (We saved the list of drawn objects with their current position and sizes that's why we can modify any object. We just need draggable functionality). I tried the solution posted here [How can I make a Rectangle on a canvas which is draggable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163559/how-can-i-make-a-rectangle-on-a-canvas-which-is-draggable) but it's only applicable in Canvas. Maybe someone can help extent it using DrawingImage so that what object has been added can be reposition using drag movement? Please help. Here's my code below. Redraw the object in the image by dragging to re-position it, would be nice.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TestDrawing.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDrawing"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid Margin="12">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Canvas>
        <Button x:Name="BtnAddRectangle" Content="Add Rectngle" Click="BtnAddRectangle_Click" Height="20"/>
      
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>

      <Canvas>
    <Image Name="myDrawing" Stretch="UniformToFill" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="-10,177,10.333,-0.333" Grid.Row="1" Height="200" />
       
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

```
CS

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestDrawing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // this creates and adds rectangles dynamically
        

        private void BtnAddRectangle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

            // Retrieve the DrawingContext in order to create new drawing content.
            DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();

            // Create a rectangle and draw it in the DrawingContext.
            Rect rect = new Rect(new Size(150, 100));
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.LightBlue, null, rect);

            // Persist the drawing content.
            drawingContext.Close();
            myDrawing.Source = new DrawingImage(drawingVisual.Drawing);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the drag-gable part? Did you try ```TranslateTransform``` class?

Comment: Any added object for example rectangle. If possible what was drawn object can be draggable, the same behavior in this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163559/how-can-i-make-a-rectangle-on-a-canvas-which-is-draggable